# Books about the development/history of gravitational theory

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, history, modified-gravity

I am looking for a book about the history of gravitational theory. It should obviously include discussions of Newton, Einstein, and their theories, and hopefully it would include the work of other famous scientists (philosophers) like Aristotle and Galileo that were part of the development. It would be great to find a book that also discusses lesser known theories, like Le Sage's, Descartes's, or Nordstrom's and theories like MOND.

I have come across three books that might fit this but am looking for recommendations of which of these, or another related book, is best.

- The Ascent of Gravity by Marcus Chown
  ("the force that explains everything".. ehh)
- Gravity's Arc by David Darling
- Gravity by George Gamow

Comment: Not a book, but here is an interesting article on the historical development of the Einstein field equations: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0610154

Comment: The intro in this article has a nice historical review: https://iopscience-iop-org.libproxy.utdallas.edu/article/10.1088/0031-9120/40/2/002

Comment: This might be better for history of science and math? https://hsm.stackexchange.com/